# Spring data and Cassandra on Tomcat - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext invokeExceptionCaught

Tags: java, tomcat, cassandra, spring-data, netty

I am developing a single sign on web application using Spring data and Cassandra. I just used the the below link as reference to create casssandra configuration and am using Tomcat.

http://myjourneyonjava.blogspot.com/2015/08/spring-data-cassandra-crud-operations.html

The issue is getting the warning message continuously. What could be the reason, how to over come that.

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext invokeExceptionCaught
WARNING: An exception was thrown by a user handler's exceptionCaught() method while handling the following exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateEvent
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler$AllIdleTimeoutTask.run(IdleStateHandler.java:433)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```